# Is it correct to use either and neither like this?

Tags: grammaticality

Suppose someone asks me:

1. Do you prefer A or B?

   - either (I like both.)
   - neither (I do not like both.)
2. I like that shirt.

   - Me either (I like that shirt too.)
3. I don't like that color.

   - Me neither (I do not like that color too.)

Do I understand correctly?

Answer (score 1):

No, "either" isn't really a valid answer to "Do you prefer A or B?". Someone might, however, say "I'll take either" or "I'll have either". It's possible some people might say "Either", but it doesn't really fit.

"Neither" doesn't mean they don't like either of them. It could mean that, but it could equally well mean that they love both and can't choose between them. It simply means "no preference". You'd have to judge by their tone of voice or by what else they said (if they expanded on their remarks).

In answer to "I like that shirt", "Me either" is ungrammatical. It would have to be "Me too" (informal) or "So do I" (more formal).

In answer to "I don't like that colour", "Me neither" or "Neither do I" or "Nor do I" can be used to agree with the sentiment and express the fact that you don't like it, either.

Answer (score 0):

"Me neither" is correct and idiomatic in colloquial language. It means "I don't, either" = "I also don't (like it)". It only works in a negative context.

"Me either" is ungrammatical.

> Do you prefer A or B?
>
> - either (I like both.)
> - neither (I do not like both.)

These both sound fine to me. In context it is clear that you mean "either one is fine"/"I like neither".